# Page not found(404) : No category matches the given query

Tags: django

Below is my error

```
Page not found(404)

No category matches the given query.

request method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/store/slug/
Raised by:  store.views.product_in_category

Using the URLconf defined in rhizomeedu_prj.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
noticeboard/
markdownx/
store/ [name='product_all']
store/ <slug:category_slug>/ [name='product_in_category']

The current path, store/slug/, matched the last one.
```

And this is the model of Category.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    meta_description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True, allow_unicode=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('store:product_in_category', args={"slug":self.slug})
```

Related part of views.py

```
def product_in_category(request, category_slug=None):
    current_category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available_display=True)

    if category_slug:
        current_category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=current_category)

    return render(request, 'store/product_list.html',
                  {'current_category': current_category, 'categories': categories, 'products': products})
```

And this is whole urls.py

```
 from django.urls import path, include
from .views import *

app_name = 'store'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', product_in_category, name="product_all"),
    path('<slug:category_slug>/', product_in_category, name="product_in_category"),
    path('<int:id>/<product_slug>/', ProductDetail.product_detail, name="product_detail"),
    path('create_product/', ProductCreate.as_view()),
    path('cart/', detail, name='detail'),
    path('add/<int:product_id>/', add, name='item_add'),
    path('remove/<int:product_id>/', remove, name='item_remove'),
    path('orders/create/', order_create, name='order_create'),
    path('orders/create_ajax/', OrderCreateAjaxView.as_view(), name='order_create_ajax'),
    path('orders/checkout/', OrderCheckoutAjaxView.as_view(), name='order_checkout'),
    path('orders/validation/', OrderImpAjaxView.as_view(), name='order_validation'),
    path('orders/complete/', order_complete, name='order_complete'),
    path('admin/order/<int:order_id>/', admin_order_detail, name='admin_order_detail'),
    path('admin/order/<int:order_id>/pdf/', admin_order_pdf, name='admin_order_pdf'),
    path('cart/', detail, name='detail'),
    path('cart/add/<int:product_id>/', add, name='product_add'),
    path('cart/remove/<int:product_id>/', remove, name='product_remove'),
]
```

Lastly, this is related part of the template product_list.html

```
<div class="py-3">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-center">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link {% if not current_category %}active{% endif %}" href="/store/">전체</a>
                </li>
                {% for c in categories %}
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link {% if current_category.slug == c.slug %}active{% endif %}" href="{{c.get_absolute_url}}" style="color:black">{{c.name}}</a>
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- Section-->
        <section class="py-5">
            <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5 mt-5">
                <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 row-cols-2 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-xl-4 justify-content-center">
                    {% for p in products %}
                    <div class="col mb-5">
                        <div class="card h-100">
                            <!-- Product image-->
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/450x300/dee2e6/6c757d.jpg" alt="..." style="opacity:0.7"/>
                            <!-- Product details-->
                            <div class="card-body p-4">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <!-- Product name-->
                                    <h5 class="fw-bolder">{{p.title}}</h5>
                                    <!-- Product price-->
                                    ￦{{p.price}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Product actions-->
                            <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
                                <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto my-1" href="{{ p.get_absolute_url }}">detail</a><a class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto my-1" href="#">add to cart</a></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
        <!-- Bootstrap core JS-->
        {% include 'single_pages/footer.html' %}
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Core theme JS-->
        <script src="{% static 'js/scripts.js' %}"></script>

    {% endblock %}
```

Every time I click category other than 'All',
it raises error mentioned before.

Also the url turns '127.0.0.1:8000/store/slug'
which is bizzare because there's no category named 'slug'.
What's wrong with my code?
Help me.

Comment: share all the `{% url ... %}`s in your code.

Comment: okay posted whole urls.py

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem realized that I answered like a dummy. Posted rest of the template above. check it out

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the official document of Django, this problem has caused by violating rules related with url and slug.
When you want to put slug into url in a form of slug(not string), it has to be only composed of ASCII components.
My slug was not, so problem solved when I changed it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is wrong:

```py
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('store:product_in_category', args={"slug":self.slug})
```

and needs to be changed to:

```py
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('store:product_in_category', args={"category_slug":self.slug})
```

Comment: followed your advice, but same results :( sorry

Answer (score 0):

Check this by changing `get_absolute_url`,

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("store:product_in_category", args=[str(self.slug)])
```

and the reason for 404 page not found error might be because there's no category object with category_slug you are passing and it shows error in this line,

```
current_category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
```

Comment: Your suggestion about changing get_absolute_url does not work. It raised another error.  thanks anyway..

Comment: What was the issue when you changed it to ```args={"category_slug":self.slug}```

Comment: After I changed it 'slug' from 'category_slug', same error occured except the url turned '127.0.0.1:8000/store/category_slug' from '127.0.0.1:8000/store/slug'.!